# TFS access denied error when doing checkin using parallels, and Visual studio 2013 on a Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, parallels

I am running visual studio with TFS in parallels on a mac. In parallels, my projects are actually pointed to the mac documents folder. I am able to open and edit projects no problem as well as push them to the server.

Recently I enabled TFS source control. Whenever I try to do an initial push or checkin, I get an "Access to path is denied" error on all the individual files.

I really do NOT want to have to put my file on the virtual machine, so can someone tell me how to fix the permissions to allow TFS to access these files and do the check in?

here is an example of the output window upon checkin...

V:\MeYearly\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.6\lib\portable-net45+wp80+win8\Newtonsoft.Json.xml: Access to the path is denied.
V:\MeYearly\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.6\Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.6.nupkg: Access to the path is denied.
V:\MeYearly\packages\Owin.1.0\lib\net40\Owin.dll: Access to the path is denied.
V:\MeYearly\packages\Owin.1.0\Owin.1.0.nupkg: Access to the path is denied.
V:\MeYearly\packages\repositories.config: Access to the path is denied.
V:\MeYearly\packages\Respond.1.2.0\content\Scripts\respond.js: Access to the path is denied.
V:\MeYearly\packages\Respond.1.2.0\content\Scripts\respond.min.js: Access to the path is denied.
V:\MeYearly\packages\Respond.1.2.0\Respond.1.2.0.nupkg: Access to the path is denied.
V:\MeYearly\packages\System.Linq.Dynamic.1.0.0\lib\net40\System.Linq.Dynamic.dll: Access to the path is denied.
V:\MeYearly\packages\System.Linq.Dynamic.1.0.0\System.Linq.Dynamic.1.0.0.nupkg: Access to the path is denied.
V:\MeYearly\packages\Twitter.Bootstrap.3.0.1.1\readme.txt: Access to the path is denied.
V:\MeYearly\packages\Twitter.Bootstrap.3.0.1.1\Twitter.Bootstrap.3.0.1.1.nupkg: Access to the path is denied.
V:\MeYearly\packages\WebGrease.1.5.2\lib\WebGrease.dll: Access to the path is denied.

Comment: You shouldn't be checking in binaries. You can set NuGet to not check in binaries by modifying the NuGet.config file.

Comment: Daniel can you provide more detail on how to do that?

Comment: https://docs.nuget.org/Consume/Package-Restore

Comment: I'm not clear on what that has to do with simply checking in something like and image that has nothing to do with packages? for example, I get the same error on this file...V:\MeYearly\packages\Respond.1.2.0\content\Scripts\respond.js: Access to the path is denied.

Its nothing more than a js file

Comment: You should exclude everything under the Packages folder from being checked in. Use .tfignore or .gitignore to resolve.

Comment: Once again, how is excluding packages going to help with things like images etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a workaround for this. I was able to check-in by shelving pending changes first.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the files locally on your virtual machine.

Checking in and out from what is in effect a remote location is not supported. If you want to have the files on your mac you can use Team Explorer Everywhere in eclipse and the command line. You would have to switch to your mac every time you want to checkin, which kinda sucks...

Comment: So what to people do that keep their files on, let's say, an external hard drive? Same issue then? Or if the hard drive is a member of the vm and not the Mac, it's ok.?

Comment: Any bon-removable drive is fine. Your workspace files are throw away. Everything of value should be checked into the TFS server or shelved. If you don't checkin for days then you are doing it wrong 

Comment: I moved the files to my local and that solved it. Not really a fan of keeping files on my VM but its nice knowing I can pull them from anywhere now with TFS!

Comment: Can I get some upvotes please? They blocked me from asking questions.

Comment: @MrHinsh Do you have a source for this restriction?  I believe you, but I'm wondering if it's intentional.  (I've seen another posts where someone filed a bug report with Microsoft about this.  Just wondering if there's any hope for a fix eventually, or if there's some good reason behind the restriction.)  Thanks.

Comment: No, but I would imagine that its the same reason that Sugar Sync or Onedrive don't support removable drive... Removed is the same as deleted...

Answer (score 4):

[Another solution without the need to shelve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41601755/802791):

> What I did was to change the local workspace to a **server workspace** in Visual Studio (macOS Sierra + Windows 10 on Parallels);
>
> - *File > Source Control > Advanced > Workspaces...*
> - Select your workspace in the list and hit *Edit...*
> - Hit *Advanced >>*
> - Change *Location* to **Server** and hit *OK* and *Close*
>
> Now you should be able to check in without needing to shelve.

Comment: Will try this on my Mac. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This is the real solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am a similar question a while back.

This used to work fine in Parallels.   I had opened a ticket with Microsoft.

We spent nearly three weeks trying to track down the issue -- but it appears a Parallels update that was release at the end of 2014 is the culprit.

As Parallels is very not very responsive to consumer complaint's we will probably not be able to get a resolution anytime in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

You will need change the configuration for the source control.
Go to File ---> Source Control----->Advanced----> WokrSpace and remove it.